# Explanation of older post: Appending a List and Recursion (Hamming Distance) - Python 3

Tags: python, recursion, hamming-distance

[An older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072112/appending-a-list-and-recursion-hamming-distance-python-3) had this code in it:

```
def hamming(num, dist):
    if dist == 0:
        return num
    else:
        outputlist = list()
        for item in range(len(num)):
            if len(num[item:]) > dist - 1:
                if num[item] == "0":
                    restoflist = hamming(num[item + 1:], dist - 1)
                    outputlist.append(num[:item] + "1" + str(restoflist))
                else:
                    restoflist = hamming(num[item + 1:], dist - 1)
                    outputlist.append(num[:item] + "0" + str(restoflist))                
        return outputlist
```

What is the reasoning behind `if len(num[item:]) > dist - 1` ?

Comment: Could you provide a link to this older post, perhaps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072112/appending-a-list-and-recursion-hamming-distance-python-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test makes sure that the sliced end of `num` is long enough to have a distance of `dist-1` from the current string. If not, there's no point in recursing. Another way of writing that test (which would be a bit more efficient) is `len(num)-item >= dist`.

But really, the check should be dropped and the `for` loop's bounds changed instead:

```
for item in range(len(num) - dist + 1):
    if num[item] == "0":
        # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

num[item:] will return a list starting at the index of item going to the end. So the length of that will get the elements until the end of the list.

dist -1 is the equivalent of saying >= dist.

Comment: It erms of Hamming distance, why is that important though?